# Exercise 8, Section 13 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

> (a) Apply lemma 13.2 to show that the countable collection $\mathcal{B}=\{(a,b)| a\lt b,$ $a,b\in \Bbb{Q}\}$ is a basis that generates the standard topology on $\Bbb{R}$.
>
> (b) Show that the collection $\mathcal{C}=\{[a,b)| a\lt b$, $a,b\in \Bbb{Q}\}$ is a basis that generates a topology different from the lower limit topology on $\Bbb{R}$.

**My attempt:** **(a)** By theorem 2.13 of Baby Rudin, $\mathcal{B}$ is countable. First we show $\mathcal{B}$ is basis. $\forall x\in \Bbb{R}, \exists p,q\in \Bbb{Q}$ such that $p\lt x \lt q$. So $x\in (p,q)$. Let $x\in (a,b)\cap (c,d)$; $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb{Q}$, $a\lt b$, $c\lt d$. WLOG $a\lt d$. Since we have finite number of points(in this case four), we can make only finite number of cases. Each point(out of a,b,c,d) is related with the other by order relation. If $b\leq c$, then $(a,b)\cap (c,d)=\phi$. So $c\lt b$. Case (1) $c\in (a,b)$/$a\lt c \lt b$ and $d\gt b$. Case (2) $c\leq a$ and $d\gt b$. Case(3) $a\lt c \lt b$ and $a\lt d \leq b$. Case(4) $c\leq a$ and $a\lt d\leq b$. It is easy to check, in each case $(a,b)\cap (c,d)\in \mathcal{B}$. So $\mathcal{B}$ satisfy second condition for basis. Thus $\mathcal{B}$ is basis.

First condition of lemma 13.2, $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{B}_{s}$(basis of standard topology)$\subseteq \mathcal{T}$. So $\mathcal{B}\subseteq \mathcal{T}$. Let $U\in \mathcal{T}$ and $x\in U$. $\exists(m,n)\in \mathcal{B}_{s}$ such that $x\in (a,b)\subseteq U$. $m,n \in \Bbb{R}$ and $n\lt m$. By theorem 1.20 of Baby Rudin, $\exists p,q \in \Bbb{Q}$ such that $a\lt p \lt x \lt q \lt b$. So $x\in (p,q)\subset (a,b)$. So, for $x\in U$, take $(p,q)\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in (p,q)\subset U$. This completes the proof. **Is this proof correct?**

**(b)** It is easy check $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis. To show two topology are not equal. Try to show $\mathcal{T}\nsubseteq \mathcal{T}^\prime$(generated by $\mathcal{C}$). Show hypothesis of lemma 13.3 don’t hold. And that’s how you solve part (b).

Comment: For (a) you just need Lemma 13.2. All elements of  $\mathcal{B}$ are open sets in the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$, let's name it $\tau$. Now, given $U \in \tau$ and $x \in U$, by definition there exist $a < b$ real numbers such that $x \in (a,b) \subset U$. Take now $p, q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a <p < x < q< b$. In this way, we have that $(p,q) \in \mathcal{B}$ and $x \in (p,q) \subset (a,b) \subset U$. So, $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies both conditions of Lemma 13.2 and it is then a basis for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Eparoh that’s what I have done.

Comment: But you don't need to show that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis. The Lemma 13.2 states that if the elements of $\mathcal{B}$ are open in some topology and if they satisfy the condition you prove, then is a basis for that topology. If you do it this way, you don't know to show first that $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies the definition for basis.

Comment: @Eparoh I showed $\mathcal{B}$ basis because I want to check the cases I considered are correct or not.

Comment: I think you don't really understand what Lemma 13.2 says. Read it carefully. If you are using that lemma, then it is not necessary to show that $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies the definition for base.

Comment: @Eparoh I understand what you’re saying. And what lemma 13.2 says. There’s no harm to show $\mathcal{B}$ is basis. I also told you, why I’m showing $\mathcal{B}$ is basis, because I want to double check the no. of cases I considered to show intersection of two intervals is a interval, is precise or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a) you just apply lemma 13.2 directly:

Let $O$ be open in $\Bbb R$ and $x \in O$. Munkres has defined the standard topology by the base $\{(a,b)\mid a,b \in \Bbb R\}$.
Ergo, for some $a < b$ we have $x \in (a,b) \subseteq O$. So $a < x < b$ and we can indeed (by the so-called order-denseness of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$) find rationals $q_1, q_2$ so that $a < q_1 < x$ and $x < q_2 < b$. It then follows that $(q_1,q_2) \in \mathcal B$ and $x \in (q_1, q_2) \subseteq (a,b) \subseteq O$. Lemma 13.2 now tells us directly that $\mathcal B$ is a base for $\Bbb R$ in its standard topology. No need for further checks: just note that the condition is satisfied and all sets in $\mathcal B$ *are* themselves already open in the standard topology.

summary: your proof was in essence OK, but had redundant elements and did more work than needed. I like my proofs neat and tidy. Matter of taste (and laziness). Also easier to check, which is important, IMO.

For b) the proof that $\mathcal C$ is a base for *some* topology is very easy: covering is trivial and $\mathcal C$ is closed under (non-empty) binary intersection, so the two base conditions are easy (see the part where Munkres checks the bases for the lower limit topology and and the standard topology in section 13)

Members of $\mathcal C$ are not standard open but *are* lower-limit open. But it is nevertheless not a base for it because we cannot find a member $C$ of $\mathcal C$ such that $\sqrt{2} \in C \subseteq [\sqrt{2},3)$ so the open set $[\sqrt{2},3)$ is not a union of members of $\mathcal C$.. So this base generates a topology strictly smaller then that of $\Bbb R_l$.

Comment: You can take general $[a,b)$, where $a\in \Bbb{Q}^c$ and $b\in \Bbb{R}$. Show there exist no $B\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $a\in B$ and $B\subseteq [a,b)$.

Comment: @user264745 true, but for the proof of not being a base for the lower limit topology one example is sufficient. The problem is not to find all lower limit opens that are not in the generated topology, just that there is at least one such set.